# Data from selectbox and checkbox

Tags: javascript, json, select

I want to get data from my select/dropdown box and from my checkboxes.
I get the data from the input fields like this:

```
 'formData'         : {
   'timestamp' : '<?php echo $timestamp;?>',
   'token'     : '<?php echo md5('unique_salt' . $timestamp);?>',
   'parentId'      : $('input[name=parentId]').val(),
   'projectnr'      : $('input[name=projectnr]').val(),
   'gebruiker'      : $('input[name=gebruiker]').val(),
   'gebruikerid'      : $('input[name=userId]').val(),
   'uploadbash'      : '<?php echo $uploadbash; ?>'
 },
```

How do I get the selected value from my `<select>` field and checkboxes?

I tried:

```
  'groepId'      : document.getElementsByName("map")
```

But it doesn't work...

---

The select looks like this:

```
<select name="map" id="map">
                                <option value="0">Algemeen</option>
                <?php
                    if(mysql_num_rows($query_select_map) != 0)  {

                        while($fetch_map = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_select_map))    {
                            if($fetch_map['parent'] != "")  {
                                $voegtoe = ">";
                            }
                            echo '<option value="'.$fetch_map['id'].'">'.$voegtoe.' '.$fetch_map['naam'].'</option>';
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                            </select>
```

Weird thing, i build in this check:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#zenden').click(function(){
alert($('#map').val());
});
});
</script>
```

When I submit I get the right number of the selected item in my alert box, but it sends the wrong number the next page.
All other data is right...

Comment: Put `get selected value checkboxes` in google. It should help.

Comment: Reading would help too, it just won't work.. i won't ask for anything if i didn't searched at google first.. Funny guy.

Comment: I posted it below, as an answer on my topic.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$("input[name=map]:checked").val();
```

Comment: I tried that one, it works on checkboxes, but i meant the selectboxes / dropdownboxes.

So now i did this:

'parentId'      : $('input[name=map]:selected').val(),

But it has no result..

Comment: Just use `$("input[name=map]").val();`

Comment: Did that, but it won't send any value..  it says: 'undefined'

Comment: When i do this:

 'mapId'      : $( "#map" ).val(),

I always get the first value of the select list. (no matter wich one is selected)
Maybe i need to add something? Any idea?